# Move an child html elements in javascript loop using insertAfter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, insertafter

I have a repeating chunk of HTML and would like to reorder the child elements using JQuery / Javascript: looking to move the description underneath the button in this simplified version.

The snippet shows roughly my logic but not working like this. Anyone able to fix this?

```js
var licount = $(".tile-group").length;
var children = $(".tile-group").children;

for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    var desc = child.querySelector(".desc");

    child.insertAfter( desc );
}
```

```css
.tile {
 margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile-group">
<div class="tile">
   <div class="title">
      Title 1
   </div>
   <div class="desc">
      Description 1
   </div>
   <div class="btn">
    <button>Button 1</button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
   <div class="title">
      Title 2
   </div>
   <div class="desc">
      Description 2
   </div>
   <div class="btn">
    <button>Button 2</button>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `querySelector` with jQuery? Mixing strategies rarely makes things simpler.

Comment: How should the final HTML look like? Will the `.desc` divs become direct children of `.tile-group`? or will they continue to be direct of `.tile-group > .tile`?

Comment: Protips: If you're using jQuery, use jQuery. Don't bring raw JavaScript methods (`querySelector`, `insertAfter()`) into the mix. Also, loops like that are rarely needed in jQuery. Sometimes it's implied by the selector, and sometimes you'd use `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is not the elements' id. It is their class. You should do

```
var desc = child.querySelector(".desc");
```

Comment: Thankyou, typo there which I've fixed in the example.  Not the solution unfortunately.

Comment: You are still using getElementById, this time with css selector. This will not work [    `var desc = child.getElementById(".desc");`]

Comment: Thanks again, have changed, but hasn't fixed the issue.